# Is there an explicit formula for this homomorphism?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Set $A$ is a finite set of whole numbers from $1$ to $n$ (for some arbitrary $n$). Constant $c$ is an arbitrary whole number. I want to partition the set into $c$ ordered groups, so that each ordered group contains every $c$-th point starting from the next offset, with the groups following each other.

For example, let's say that $c = 4$ and $n = 12$.

Then $A$ would equal $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12\}$

And my 4 "ordered groups" would be:

$\{1,5,9\}, \{2,6,10\}, \{3,7,11\}, \{4,8,12\}$

So the homomorphism I'm describing would map $A$ to $B$,
where $B$ is equal to $\{1,5,9,2,6,10,3,7,11,4,8,12\}$

This example is rather convenient because here $c$ is a factor of $n$. But I'm wondering about the general case for any value of $c$ or $n$. Is there an explicit formula $f(n)$ (for a given value of $c$) for rearranging $A$ in this manner? (So in this particular example, $f(2)=5$ and $f(10)=4$.)

I'm a computer scientist so I know how to rearrange $A$ with modulo arithmetic and multiple steps to achieve this homomorphism. But I'm wondering if it's possible to pare this concept down to a single explicit formula, mathematically. Thanks.

Comment: In what sense is the function you want a homomorphism?

Comment: In that it maps set A to set B? Am I using the wrong term perhaps?

Comment: A homomorphism is a function that preserves some structure. It is particularly confusing because you use the word group (instead of the preferred word: set), and we do talk about homomorphisms between groups.

What I think you want is a function $f$ from the set $A = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to itself which is one-one and onto, so your function just "rearranges" the set. We call such a function a permutation.

If this is what you want I can actually answer your question.

Comment: Why not use modular arithmetic? That would be the easiest ways. Even an "explicit" formula would likely involve floor/ceiling functions, or mods, or something of that sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, fix $n$ and let $A = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Now also fix $c$, for your problem to make sense we need $c\leq n-1$.

We know there are $q$ and $r$ so that $n = qc + r$ where $r<c$. Now we need to split into two cases, $r=0$ and $r\neq 0$.

If $r = 0$ then your rearrangement looks something like:

$
(1,\ 1+c,\ 1+2c,\ldots ,\ 1+ (q-1)c,\ 2,\ 2+c,\ 2+2c, \ldots,\ 2+ (q-1)c , \ 3,\ldots, c,\ 2c,\ldots, qc(=n))
$

When $r >0$ the first $r$ "ordered groups" as you call them will have an extra element $qc+1,qc+2, \ldots, qc+r$.

You could write this all out explicitly, but as NotNotLogical points out, a tidy expression will require lots of floors, ceilings and mods.